# Unable to delete a datafactory due to it's association with SHIR

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am unable to delete a datafactory in Azure due it's association with self hosted IR. This SHIR is being using with another datafactory so I cannot delete it. How can I dis-associate this SHIR with the datafactory that i'd like to delete? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete the ADF (Primary) in which the SHIR is deployed, then you don't have any other option than first stop the SHIR and then delete this ADF.

If the SHIR is used but another ADF (Secondary) and you need to delete that ADF, first delete the linked services and other resources in that Azure Data Factory which is using SHIR and then delete that Azure Data Factory.

There is no scope to move/copy the SHIR to another ADF. And therefore, you can't delete the ADF in which it has been deployed.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. The secondary ADF has no resource and that is why I want to delete it.  You haver mentioned to remove the linked services. In my case the only linked service/resource is SHIR. How do I remove it without effecting the functional ADF?